# Roslyn - Get TypeInfo of type parameter in another TypeInfo

Tags: c#, roslyn

Starting with a `TypeInfo` object that represents a generic type, I want to retrieve `TypeInfo`s for each type parameter of the generic type.  I would like to expose this as an extension method with this signature:

```
public static TypeInfo[] GetTypeParameterInfos(this TypeInfo genericType) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

If I pass in a `TypeInfo` representing `List<int>`, it should return an array that contains 1 `TypeInfo` representing `int`.  If I pass in a `TypeInfo` represnting `Dictionary<int, string>`, it should return an array with an `int` and a `string` `TypeInfo`.

Is this possible? How?

---

**Update/Solution:**

To clarify, I was asking about `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypeInfo`, not `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`.  This name confusion has been a real problem in getting meaningful Google results.  However, it looks like what I really want is `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ITypeSymbol`, which can be easily acquired from a Roslyn `TypeInfo` with the `TypeInfo.Type` property.

The solution is in the `INamedTypeSymbol.TypeArguments` property, which returns an `ImmutableArray<ITypeSymbol>` corresponding to the type arguments of the given type symbol.

```
TypeInfo myGenericType = GetTypeInfoSomehow();
ImmutableArray<ITypeSymbol> typeArguments = myGenericType.Type.TypeArguments;
```

Comment: Do you mean Roslyn `ITypeSymbol` or Reflection `TypeInfo`?  They have nothing to do with eachother.

Comment: I mean Roslyn's `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypeInfo`, not `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`.  Roslyn also has the `ITypeSymbol` interface, which can be acquired from a `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypeInfo`, so I can use a solution based around `ITypeSymbol` also.

Comment: I keep running into search results for `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the [source](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/TypeInfo.cs), Roslyn's `TypeInfo` is a very thin wrapper around `ITypeSymbol`; that is where you need to look to get anything useful about the type.

If the type is in fact a generic type (as opposed to special types like arrays or pointers), it will actually be an [INamedTypeSymbol](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/INamedTypeSymbol.cs), which has all the APIs necessary to investigate the type.

In your case, you just want [its `TypeArguments` property](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/INamedTypeSymbol.cs,75).